# How do you parse a string with numbers and chars and separate the numbers and chars if there is no spaces in the string?

Tags: c++, parsing, ifstream, strtok

I have a string

```
123test
```

how do I separate 123 and test and store the in two variables?

Comment: Convert to a char array, loop through the array, and assign each character to its applicable variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use sscanf, for example:

```
char str[] = "123test";
char str2[10];
int i;

sscanf(str, "%d%s", &i, str2);
```

Comment: "test" will be in str2 and 123 will be in i. Just make sure that str2 is big enough for whatever you are trying to get.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tools provided by C++: strings and streams.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    int num;
    std::string str;

    std::istringstream ss{"123test"};
    ss >> num >> str;

    std::cout << "num = " << num << std::endl;
    std::cout << "str = " << str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Link to demo](http://rextester.com/DZKJ88769)